# java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to double

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterGrade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double Grade;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert first grade: ");
        Grade = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Insert second grade: ");
        Grade = Grade + scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Insert third gade: ");
        Grade = Grade + scanner.next();
        System.out.print(Grade);


    }
}
```

Not exactly sure what Im doing wrong here... But this is the error Im getting:

```
Error:(10, 29) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to double
Error:(12, 23) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to double
Error:(14, 23) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to double
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: I think you might want [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()), which will return a double, vs [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) which returns a String.

Comment: you want to use nextLine() and then attempt to parse the result string into a double and if the value is incorrect, try asking again

Answer (score 1):

You are using method `next()` - this method returns `String`. You then want to assign this `String` to `Grade`, which is of type `double`. You need to convert `String` to `double` or parse input `String` to `double` value. Here are possible ways how you can achieve that:

1. Instead of using `scanner.next()` try using `scanner.nextDouble()`, but be aware that after each call of `nextDouble()` you need to get rid of remaining new line character (after pressing `Enter` to confirm your input new line character is created and you want to get rid of it) with calling `scanner.nextLine()`.
2. You might want to consider using parsing method instead of calls of `nextDouble()` and `nextLine()`. There is `parseDouble()` method in class `Double` that can help you get `Double` value from input `String`:
   `Grade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine())` to automatically get rid of remaining new line character.